# User loading after authentication with ember simple auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I use ember simple auth to authenticate my users.
It workls perfectly fine except when the user just logged in.

I have an helper that ask for the current user :

```js
import Helper from '@ember/component/helper';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Helper.extend({
  currentUser: service('current-user'),
  compute([feature,currentUser]) {
    let role = currentUser.get('user.role')
```

Helper is used in a template embedded in a template in application.hbs

```
{{#if (permission-for "users" currentUser)}}
  <li>{{#link-to 'users'}}<i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Clients</span>{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/if}}
```

The current user service is a duplicate of this one from the doc : https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/guides/managing-current-user.md#loading-the-user-with-its-id

And my application.js is also using the code from the same guide.

From what I tried, the `sessionAuthenticated` start to run, and during `await this._loadCurrentUser();` the helper is executed, and it finish to run `sessionAuthenticated`

What happen is that the user attribute I want is undefined and it make it impossible to display interface elements according to the role of the User.

How can I fix this problem?

Edit for related question :How does ember simple auth is supposed to be used in template to determine if User is supposed to see some part of the interface or not ? Like for example menu choices.

Comment: How are you using the helper exactly?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is the helper is being executed synchronously and isn't "watching" the `currentUser` service in a way that would recompute. It would be a lot easier to use a computed property to do what you want:

**controllers/application.js**

```
  currentUser: service(),

  hasPermissionForUsers: computed("currentUser.user", function() {
    const user = this.get("currentUser.user");

    if (! user) return false;

    return user.get("role") === "users"; // taking a random guess at what your helper does here
  })
```

This property will now re-compute once the user is loaded:

**application.hbs**

```
  {{#if hasPermissionForUsers}}
    <li>{{#link-to 'users'}}<i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Clients</span>{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/if}}
```

If you have to use a helper, it is doable but it's not pretty. The reason it's not as elegant is because helpers don't have access to the same context so it's more difficult to recompute. You could do something like this:

```
import Helper from '@ember/component/helper';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { run } from '@ember/runloop';
import { addObserver, removeObserver } from '@ember/object/observers';

export default Helper.extend({

  currentUser: service(),

  willDestroy() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    const container = this.get('_container');
    removeObserver(container, 'currentUser.user', this, this.update);
  },

  compute([feature, container]) {
    addObserver(container, 'currentUser.user', this, this.update);
    this.set('_container', container); // used for cleanup

    const user = this.get('currentUser.user');

    if (! user) return false;

    return user.get('role') === feature;
  },

  update() {
    run.once(this, this.recompute);
  }
});
```

Then use it like so:

**application.hbs**

```
{{#if (permission-for "users" this)}}
  <li>{{#link-to 'users'}}<i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Clients</span>{{/link-to}}</li>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend to not pass the `currentUser` service to the helper if you inject it to the service.

Next you can let the helper recompute after the user was loaded:

```
export default Helper.extend({
  currentUser: service('current-user'),
  init() {
    if(!this.currentUser.user) {
      this.currentUser.runAfterLoaded.push(() => this.recompute());
    }
  },
  compute([feature]) {
    if(!this.currentUser.user)
      return false;
    }
    let role = this.currentUser.get('user.role')
    ...
    return ..;
  }
});
```

you'll also want to add `this.runAfterLoaded.forEach(x => x())` to the `load()` function in the `current-user` service after the `this.set('user', user);` as well as `this.set('runAfterLoaded', [])` to the `init` hook.

---

Another possibility is to build a mixin that you add to the relevant routes after the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` that ensures the current user will be loaded.